How to setup React + Vite + TailwindCSS to be able to use style tag?
I was working on a custom progress bar when I wanted to use the <style> tag to customize the progress value indicator. However, the css was not recognized. How do I have to configure my project that the following works:
const css = `
    progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
        @apply bg-green-400
    }
`

function CustomProgress() {
    return (
        <>
            <style>{css}</style>
            <progress />
        </>
    )
}

